# Should i write all my function in an utility-class or in a service-class?

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I am currently working on a project which dealing with XML in text file. I want to extract the content and i want to add it to the table tt_content. My question is where should I put the all functions (upload-file, extract-content,insert-tt_content)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Utilities are for static functionality that does not depend on a state. Good examples are `PathUtility` and `StringUtility`. Once you call a function, it gets the job done and nothing further.

Services on the other hand can handle state and are usually more complex. You could have some kind of `DownloadService` that is initialized with an URL, then fetches it and finally does some kind of post processing. A core example would be the `MarkerBasedTemplateService`.

As a rule of thumb, a utility does not have dependencies and does not call other (non-static) methods. Services are more complex and might call other services. Services may have an internal state.

Also make sure to check the core documentation regarding architectural guidelines: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CodingGuidelinesReference/latest/PhpArchitecture/ModelingCrossCuttingConcerns/StaticMethods/Index.html

Comment: In Spring, I have validation logic for the request and it require checking the database (which involve state). Does it make sense to have it as a validationService that is initialize with the repository, OR make it validationUtils but the static method parameter take in the repository?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your functions into a UtilityClass or in a ServiceClass or (I think the better way) you use both. Group your functions by task, e.g. StringUtility, FileUtility etc. Your ServiceClass use than the needed UtilityFunction.

So you have little functions and you can use it again and again. For example have a look in other great extension as tx_news, femanager, etc.

Comment: Just a remark: there is a new chapter in the coding guidelines regarding PHP architecture in the TYPO3 universe: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CodingGuidelinesReference/latest/PhpArchitecture/Index.html

It's a very good read and every TYPO3 developer should know it :)